# javascript showmodaldialog is not showing scrollbars

Tags: javascript

I am sorry if this is a duplicate. Please show me if it is a duplicate. I am opening a modal popup using javascript like below. But it is not showing scrollbars in IE 11. I have a grid/table inside it with long width then the popup window. I am expecting horizontal and vertical scrollbars but it is not showing.

```
function ShowModalWindowPopup(popUpURL, windowProperties, w, h) {
try {
    var left = (screen.width / 2) - (w / 2);
    var top = (screen.height / 2) - (h / 2);
    var properties = windowProperties + "width=" + w + ", height=" + h + ", top=" + top + ", left=" + left + ", scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes";
    var childWindow = window.showModalDialog(popUpURL, "", windowProperties);
}
catch (err) {
    alert("Error occured while opening ShowModalWindowPopup popup: " + err);
}
}
```

**[UPDATE]**
I was able to fix it. It was just a simple typo error that took my one complete day and caused me lot of frustration

```
function ShowCDEventsWindow(popUpURL, windowProperties, w, h) {
try{
    var left = (screen.width / 2) - (w / 2);
    var top = (screen.height / 2) - (h / 2);

    var properties = windowProperties + "dialogwidth:" + w + "px;dialogheight:" + h + "px;dialogtop:" + top + "px;dialogleft:" + left + "px;scroll:yes; resizable:yes; center:yes";
    var childWindow = window.showModalDialog(popUpURL, "", properties);
}
catch(err)
{
    alert("Error occured while opening CD Events popup :" + err)
}
```

In below line instead of passing properties, I was passing windowProperties and that was reason why all the properties I set to my dialog were not taking effect.

var childWindow = window.showModalDialog(popUpURL, "", properties);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the documentation for showModalDialog here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/showModalDialog   The rules should be seperated by semi-colons not commas, and you should use colons instead of equals. Also the variable is `scroll` not `scrollbars`. So like this:

```
var properties = windowProperties + "dialogwidth:" + w + ";dialogheight:" + h + ";dialogtop:" + top + ";dialogleft:" + left + ";scroll:on; resizable:on";
```

Comment: I tried all. But no matter what ever I do scroll bars are not shown in IE 11. I even saw this, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536759%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: You pointed me in correct direction. I was able to fix it. It was simple typo error. Please see my question above.